# Convert my simple 'for loop' into an apply function

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply, mapply

I'm trying to embrace the `apply` family more, but still having trouble. I mostly understand simple cases with `lapply` (as below), but am having issues with more complicated `apply` functions.

I have a `for` loop function that iterates through a nested list and adds a new subset list.  How could I write this using the `apply` family of functions?

```
mylist <- list(mtcars=mtcars, iris=iris)

mylist <- lapply(mylist,
 function(sub) list(data=sub))

for (i in head(seq_along(mylist))){
  mylist[[i]]$new <- mylist[[i]]$data[,c(1,4,5)]
}
```

Which gives:

```
> mylist$mtcars$new
                     mpg  hp drat
Mazda RX4           21.0 110 3.90
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0 110 3.90
Datsun 710          22.8  93 3.85
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4 110 3.08

> mylist$iris$new

    Sepal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5.1         0.2     setosa
2            4.9         0.2     setosa
3            4.7         0.2     setosa
4            4.6         0.2     setosa
```

Comment: `lapply(mylist, function(lst) { lst$new <- lst$data[c(1,4,5)]; lst;})`?

Comment: `apply` is used for objects with dimensions.

Comment: @r2evans, this works, but could u walk thru it? Is `lst` from `dplyr` or just a variable name? Function of `;`? Really trying to make sure I understand...thanks

Comment: No, `lst` here is just a temporary variable named in the anonymous function, ala `function(lst) {...}`. It could have been `a` or `some_other_variable_name`, as long as the inner code reference that name instead of `lst`. As for the semi-colon: typically lines of code in R are terminated or separated with a newline, but a semi-colon can be used as well. I really only use semi-colons here on SO in comments, otherwise I tend to use multi-line calls.

Comment: Ahh. Any idea why the output is different depending on why the `lst` call at the end is included?

Comment: Yes. The return value from the assignment line of code is (invisibly) the *values assigned*, not the whole object `lst`. You need the whole (updated) object returned, so you need to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

To create such a nested list is not necessary and complicating stuff.
Keep it simple: Take the initial list and create a new list for new tables.

```
olds <- list(mtcars=mtcars, iris=iris)
news <- lapply(mylist, function(df) df[, c(1, 4, 5)])
```

Both lists have then the data frame names ("mtcars" and "iris") in common, so it is easy to select from the `news` list and the `olds` list the corresponding data frame for each other.

```
# access the new data frame from the old data frame `iris`
news[["iris"]] # news[["mtcars"]]
# returns the corresponding new data frame of the "iris" data frame.

# return original data frame
olds[["iris"]] # olds[["mtcars"]]
```